# MySql Error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '******_******'@'********************' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I was staring to learning MySql, and then I try to connect to it this error appear:

```
Error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '******_******'@'*******************l' (using password: YES)
```

main.py

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="mysql1.mydevil.net",
    user="******_******",
    passwd="****************",
    database="******_test_db"
)
```

I am using mydevil.net hosting. I think that information is helpfull.
If you are asking why I am not doing it local, because I have Win8.1 and MySQL WB just stop working then I try to run the server. And CLI is trying to connect to don't existing server and just crashes instantly after passing password.

Comment: Typically this error is thrown due to invalid credentials, or a user is not allowed to login remotely.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
    host="mysql1.mydevil.net",
```

to

```
    host="localhost",
```

This should fix it.